# Program freezes during the generation of a variable in a while cicle in JAVA

Tags: java, rsa, freeze

In my school, teachers told has to write a program that encrypts a number with the RSA encryption. The whole program works just fine, except for a small part, that sometimes freezes the program when gets executed.
Here's the code of the class:

```
package newpackage;

import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CrittografiaRSA {
    public static Random rand = new Random();
    public static double d;
    public static String cod;
    public static int e;

    public static boolean EuclideAlgorithm(int a, int b) {
        int r;
        boolean k = false;
        while (b != 0) {
            r = a % b;
            a = b;
            b = r;

        }
        if (a == 1) {
            k = true;
        }
        if (a != 1) {
            k = false;
        }
        return k;
    }


    public static String RSA(int p, int q, String mex, int e) {
        CrittografiaRSA.cod = "";
        int pqless, n, i = 0, v;
        boolean GCD = false, dVerify = false, PQPN;

        PQPN = EuclideAlgorithm(p, q);

        if (PQPN == false) {
            cod = "P e Q non sono primi fra loro";
            return cod;
        }

        n = p * q;
        pqless = (q - 1) * (p - 1);

        if (NewJFrame.generateE == true) {
            while (GCD == false || e >= pqless || e == 1) {
                e = rand.nextInt(pqless);
                System.out.println(e);
                GCD = EuclideAlgorithm(e, pqless);
            }
        }

        if (NewJFrame.generateE == false) {
            GCD = EuclideAlgorithm(e, pqless);
            if (GCD == false || e >= pqless || e == 1) {
                cod = "La E fornita non è adatta.";
                return cod;
            }
        }
        CrittografiaRSA.d = e;
        while (e == CrittografiaRSA.d || d == 0) {

            while (dVerify == false) {
                CrittografiaRSA.d = ((i * pqless) + 1) / (double) e;
                v = (int) d;
                if (d == v) {
                    dVerify = true;
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }
            if (e == i && NewJFrame.generateE == false) {
                cod = "Nessuna chiave D generabile con le chiavi inserite";
                return cod;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("La chiave pubblica è: (" + n + "," + e + ")\n" + "La chiave privata è: (" + n + "," + (int) d + ")");
        if (NewJFrame.cryptoChar == false) {

            int mexx = Integer.parseInt(mex);
            if (n <= mexx) {
                cod = "Messaggio troppo grande per le chiavi fornite";
                return cod;
            }

            long c;
            double pot = Math.pow(mexx, e);
            c = (long) (pot % n);
            CrittografiaRSA.cod = Long.toString(c);

        }


        return CrittografiaRSA.cod;
    }
}
```

In particular, the program freezes right here:

```
    if(NewJFrame.generateE==true){
        while(GCD == false || e>=pqless || e==1){
            e = rand.nextInt(pqless);
            System.out.println(e);
            GCD = EuclideAlgorithm(e, pqless);
        }
    }
```

I noticed, however, that the smaller are p and q, the higher are the chances of to bug.

Hope the code is understandable, I removed the italian comments 'cause IDK if the whole code is really necessary, but whatever. 
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Just a quick note: you don't need to `import java.lang.*`. That package is implicitly imported. Also, you don't need to check `== true` for booleans in if statements; you can just put the boolean variable there (like this: `if(NewJFrame.generateE) {`).

Comment: Is it really "freezing" or is it just running the while loop forever because the condition (GCD == false || e>=pqless || e==1) is always evaluating to true for some reason?

Comment: It freezes, cause it stops printing "e" too.

Comment: Sounds like it's stuck in `while(b != 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
while(b != 0)
{
     r = a % b;
     a = b; 
     b = r;
     System.out.println(b); // add this
}
```

Is application still freezing after this modification?

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment? Looks more like a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If `p` or `q` are equal to `1` then `e` will always be equal to `pqless` because `rand.nextInt(pqless)` generates a random number between `0` and `pqless`. With a value of `1` for `p` and/or `q`, `pqless = 0` so `e = 0`. Thus, the infinite loop begins.

```
pqless = (q - 1) * (p - 1);

    if (NewJFrame.generateE == true) {
        while (GCD == false || e >= pqless || e == 1) {
            e = rand.nextInt(pqless);
            System.out.println(e);
            GCD = EuclideAlgorithm(e, pqless);
        }
    }
```